# Azure SQL Server ad-admin create ValidationError

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface, admin

When I run the following `az-cli` commands (as part of a larger script), it fails with the error:

> ValidationError: The 'parameters.properties.sid' segment in the url is invalid.

I couldn't find any info on this error.

What should be done to fix?

```
# Set Admin Security Group Object ID
export aadObjectId=$(az ad group show --group 'cc_ADMINS' --query 'objectId')

# Set Admin Group as SQL AD Admin
az sql server ad-admin create \
    --display-name 'cc_ADMINS' \
    --object-id $aadObjectId\
    --resource-group $resourceGroup \
    --server-name $serverName
```

Comment: Sounds very similar to ['postgres server ad-admin create' fails if --object-id is surrounded with quotes (") #16620](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16620).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the `$aadobjectid` contains any Double Quotes (") and remove them if present, to see if the issue is persistent.

There is an issue reported and open at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16620

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the answer in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli#get-a-single-value).

To remove the `""` around the returned object, use the `--output tsv` flag.